# Pytest complains about fixtures, then runs fine on nearly identical code

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to learn pytest, and I'm having a hard time understanding the behavior of parameterize().

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parameterize("foo", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ])
def test(foo):
    assert foo % 2 == 0
```

Running py.test on this returns an error: 'fixture 'foo' not found'.

Running this nearly identical example code works perfectly fine!  What's the difference, why is my attempt at using parametrize failing?

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("blarg,argle", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 6), ("6*9", 42), ])
def test_eval(blarg, argle):
    assert eval(blarg) == argle
```

Comment: I disagree actually, because pytest does not alert you that you are misspelling something.  (And in fact `parameterize` is a valid alternate spelling in English)

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately it's just a typo in `parametrize` word,

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("foo", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ])
def test(foo):
    assert foo % 2 == 0
```

works great.

Comment: Oh...wow.  That wasted a lot of time....heh.

Comment: Newer versions of pytest will now show this error message:

    `MarkerError: test has 'parameterize', spelling should be 'parametrize'`